# Passing JSON as parameter in URL objective-c

Tags: ios, json, web-services, rest, nsurlconnection

I have following web service url:

```
NSString *url = @"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cinema?keys=name,rows,column&where={\"location\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Location\",\"objectId\":\"gSEpGR28iT\"}}";
```

here parameter for `where` is itself in JSON format

Problem is when i consume this web service using following code it gives error:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:PARSE_APPLICATION_ID_VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:PARSE_APPLICATION_ID_KEY];
[request addValue:PARSE_REST_ID_VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:PARSE_REST_ID_KEY];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:command.request
                                   queue:self.operationQueue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data,
                                           NSError *error)
 {
   ...
 }]
```

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7c989590 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

If i use same web service without `where` parameter i.e. only `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Cinema?keys=name,rows,column` code works fine. I don't know why a parameter in json format is causing problem. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe because of the character "&"?

Comment: but it works fine if i test it on rest client extension for browser

Comment: I think iOS doesn't allow couple of characters in string. I think you need to add something... try adding %@

Comment: Yeah, you probably have to do some URL parameter encoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673127/how-to-send-post-or-get-request-containing-json-to-a-url