# How to read http status code for HEAD request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm requesting an API with AFNetworking 4.3.1 and Http method **GET** and **HEAD**. It could return different http status code (100, 200, 402, ..)

My **get** function request working fine.

```
-(void) getApiV2:(NSString *)url
      parameters:(NSDictionary *)param
         success:(successBlock)mSuccessBlock
         failure:(failureBlock)mfailureBlock{

    NSMutableDictionary *httpHeader =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if(TOKEN !=nil){
        [httpHeader setObject:TOKEN forKey:@"Token"];
    }

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager
        GET:url
        parameters:param
        headers:httpHeader
        progress:nil
        success: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject){
            int statusCode = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
            NSArray *data = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
            BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(mSuccessBlock,data,statusCode);
        }
        failure: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask, NSError * error){
            BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(mfailureBlock,error);
        }
    ];
};
```

But my **head** function throw error.

```
-(void) head:(NSString *)url success:(successBlock)mSuccessBlock failure:(failureBlock)mfailureBlock{

    NSMutableDictionary *httpHeader =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if(TOKEN !=nil){
        [httpHeader setObject:TOKEN forKey:@"Token"];
    }

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager
        HEAD:url
        parameters:nil
        headers:httpHeader
        success: ^(id _Nullable responseObject){
            int statusCode = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
            BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(mSuccessBlock,responseObject,statusCode);
        }
        failure: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask, NSError * error){
            BLOCK_SAFE_RUN(mfailureBlock,error);
        }
    ];
};
```

At run time, I have this error on the line `int statusCode = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];`

> [__NSCFLocalDataTask objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x110f88860

The server properly handle the request and do it job.

---

I try other syntax:

```
int statusCode = (int) [responseObject statusCode];
```

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFLocalDataTask statusCode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145731af0'

from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016361/nsurlsession-request-and-response)

```
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)responseObject;
            int statusCode = (int) httpResponse.statusCode;
```

> [__NSCFLocalDataTask statusCode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x129665ed0

---

What is the good way to get the http status code for a **HEAD** request with AFNetworking?

Comment: `responseObject` is a `NSCFLocalDataTask`, which should be, I guess a `URLSessionTask`. Try to print it first. `NSLog(@"Response tasks: %@", responseObject);` But then, it's that's one: `URLSessionTask *task = (URLSessionTask *)responseObject;  NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response];  int statusCode = (int) httpResponse.statusCode;`

Comment: @Larme, Thanks for your help. now its work with 
`    NSURLSessionTask *task = (NSURLSessionTask *)responseObject;    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response];    int statusCode = (int) httpResponse.statusCode;    NSLog(@"Status code: %d", statusCode);`
You could write an answer so I approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Larme and confirmed by the [source code of AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m#L142), `HEAD:parameters:headers:success:failure:` return a `NSURLSessionDataTask`

So I need to retrieve the `NSHTTPURLResponse` before I can get the `statusCode`.

```
NSURLSessionTask *task = (NSURLSessionTask *)responseObject;
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)[task response];
int statusCode = (int) httpResponse.statusCode;
NSLog(@"Status code: %d", statusCode);
```