# Data posting error through PHP Web service in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this link [How to send POST and GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673127/how-to-send-post-and-get-request) . Method to POST my form data to a php web service but when i hit submit button it shows this error: requestReply: 
**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null' in /var/sites/p/pk.house/public_html/app_webservices/add_buyer_request.php:35
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/sites/p/pk.house/public_html/app_webservices/add_buyer_request.php(35): PDOStatement->execute()

## 1 {main}

thrown in **/var/sites/p/pk.house/public_html/app_webservices/add_buyer_request.php** on line **35**
. I don't no how to solve it. i have searched a lot but all the results shows some PHP code.I have checked my service it is running fine, I don't know where the actual issue is coming can anyone guide me please how to handle this?

Comment: It is some issue from server side as the error itself tells you. Some issue in line number 35 of php file add_buyer_request.php

Comment: I think you are trying to insert null to the description column of your database. Either pass correct value or change the constraint of that column to accept null values